Set of polynomials and dimension stability under addition
I consider the subset $\mathcal{U}\subset\mathbb{R}_{2}[x_1,x_2]\times \mathbb{R}_{2}[x_1,x_2]$ defined by
$$
\mathcal{U} = \{(x_1,x_2)\in[0,1]^2\mapsto (ax_1,b(1-x_1)x_2 : (a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2\}
$$
and I am interested on the set of coefficients associated to $\mathcal{U}$. More specifically, for a function $u\in\mathcal{U}$ defined by
$$
u(x_1,x_2) = (u_1(x_1,x_2),u_2(x_1,x_2))
$$
With
$$
u_j(x_1,x_2) = \sum_{(i_{1},i_{2})\in\mathbb{N}^{2},i_1+i_2\leq 2}a_
{i_{1},i_{2}}^{j}x_{1}^{i_1}x_{2}^{i_2},\quad j=1,2
$$
I defined the mapping
$$
\varphi(u)=(a_{i_{1},i_{2}}^{j})_{i_1 + i_2 \leq 2,j=1,2,a_{i_{1},i_{2}}^{j}\neq 0}
$$
that associated to a polynomial function it’s set of non zero coefficients.
I am interested on conditions under which the dimension of the space $\varphi(\mathcal{U})$ (if it has a vector space structure) is stable (or not)  when adding a set of linear mapping.
To start with the dimension of $\varphi(\mathcal{U})$:
We have $(a,b,-b)$ as coefficients associated to a polynomial function in $\mathcal{U}$. Clearly a set of such vectors is a subspace and it has dimension $2$ since $(a,b,-b)=a(1,0,0) + b((0,1,-1)$, the independance of the two vectors generating $(a,b,-b)$ is direct. Hence
$$
\dim(\varphi(\mathcal{U})) = 2\implies \varphi(\mathcal{U})\cong\mathbb{R}^2
$$
Now I define the set
$$
\mathcal{L} = \{(x_1,x_2\in[0,1]^2\mapsto (cx_1,dx_2) : (c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^2\}
$$
Then
$$
\mathcal{U+L} =  \{(x_1,x_2)\in[0,1]^2\mapsto ((a+c)x_1,(b(1-x_1)+ d)x_2 : (a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^4\}
$$
Then the associated set of coefficients $\varphi(\mathcal{U+L})$ is defined by vectors of the form $(a+c,b+d,-b) = (\tilde{a},\tilde{b},-b)$ which is a $3$ dimensional vector space. Hence
$$
\dim(\varphi(\mathcal{U+L}))\neq\dim\varphi(\mathcal{U})
$$
So I should add hypothesis on $\mathcal{L}$ to keep the same dimension but I do not see of what kinds, if you have some hints/ideas to provide please.
Thank you a lot

Context : I get interested in this question because I was asking, on the particular case above, what happens if we restrict the coefficients of linear mappings in $\mathcal{L}$ to $(0,\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon>0$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$

@AnneBauval Thank you for your comment ! Indeed I was wrong in the words used, $\phi$ provides just an identification, I have corrected my post !

Sorry, it is me who was wrong, for not having read your post carefully. Now another comment: your "map $\varphi$ that associated to a polynomial function it’s "set" of coefficients" is not clearly defined. What do you consider as the coefficients of $ ((a+c)x_1,(b(1-x_1)+ d)x_2$? I would rather say $(a+c,b+d,-b)$ (and actually, many other coefficients, all equal to $0$).

I think the only way to get $\dim(\varphi(\mathcal{U+L}))=\dim\varphi(\mathcal{U})$ is to choose $\mathcal L\subseteq\mathcal U$.

@AnneBauval Thank you a lot  for the comments, you allowed me to clarify my thoughts (I updated the post), I was too fast in the post and make mistake (as you pointed at for the example). I will try to prove your thought on this (because in fact it would be a little bit disappointing, for the applications, if this is true..)

@AnneBauval You were right !
